# Why doesn't $dA$ of a circle = $\pi r^2\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}?$

Tags: derivatives, area

Why isn't this acceptable for the derivative of the area of a circle with respect to \theta, multiplying by d\theta, dA is

$$\pi r^2\frac{d\theta}{2\pi}?$$

Essentially it is the area of the circle times dtheta/2*pi, the percentage of the circle.

Comment: What is $\theta$ when talking about a circle? A circle always has the same total angle, so it doesn’t make sense.

Comment: You might write the area of a circle wedge in terms of $\theta$ and $r,$ then $A=\frac{ r^2\theta}{2}.$ Then there are two derivatives, $\frac{dA}{dr}=r\theta$ and $\frac{dA}{d\theta}=\frac{r^2}2.$ But that is different from the derivative of a circle’s area.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations.

Comment: Note, $dA$ is not a derivative. $\frac{dA}{dt}$ is a derivative, for some $t$ on which $A$ depends. But the area of a circle does not depend on $\theta.$ Or, alternatively, $\theta$ is constant, so it doesn’t mean anything to define $\lim_{\theta\to 2\pi} f(\theta)$ when there are no values other than $\theta=2\pi$ where $f$ is defined.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. One is an area (2 dimensional) and the other is an angle (1 dimensional). What you asked makes as much sense to me as: why can we not simply write $\iint f(x, y) \;dx\,dy = \int f(x) \;dx$ or what kind of liquid is a book?

Comment: Yes, i edited it. i meant \frac{dA}{dtheta} and then multiplying by dtheta on both sides. This mathjax is not working for me.

Comment: @TrevorGunn The equation is trying to calculate a certain percentage of the area by using dtheta/2*pi where 2*pi = 360 degrees

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the area of a circular sector, subtending an angle $\theta$ at the center, then its area is

$ A(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} r^2 \theta $

And the derivative is

$ \dfrac{dA}{d\theta} = \frac{1}{2} r^2 $

So

$ dA = \frac{1}{2} r^2 d \theta $

which is what you have.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But if you think about my equation by itself, mathematically it sounds sound. the infinitesimal area dA is just the area of the circle itself times the infinitesimal angle divided by the total angle (a fraction of the area of the circle)

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Comment: since $\theta = 2*\pi, A(\theta) = \pi*r^2$